# Discovering Carrier from SIM card with AT commands

Tags: apn

I'm using a Fibocom G600/G610 GSM/GPRS modem module and would like to interrogate the SIM card to discover which carrier it supports so that I can connect using the correct APN.

Does anyone know whether this is possible and if so, how to do it?

Thanks all.

Ron

Comment: What does the documentation for the modem AT command set say?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, as:
First, AT+CIMI command to get SIM's IMSI;
Second, get country and operator from digit 1-3 and digit 4-5 of the IMSI